# Crop or resize images before upload to the server as raw image binary data (png or jpeg)

Tags: javascript, image, crop

I am trying to crop images in the browser and upload them to a server as ***raw image binary data*** (the format should be ***"image/jpeg"*** or ***"image/png"***). I tried many client-side crop & upload methods, they all use the html 5 function canvas.toDataURL() to get the final cropped data in ***"data:image/png;base64"*** format, upload it to the web server and then convert it into ***raw image binary data*** at the server side.

The thing is that I have to upload the cropped data into a static file server like AWS S3 which can't execute converting code, except for accepting file uploading. Therefore, what I need is to upload the cropped images as a ***normal image format*** like "image/png". If this can be done, I can use the browser to crop & upload images directly to the file server (S3) and I don't need a middle server to convert the image data and transfer it to the file server (S3).

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear. Do you guys understand it now?

Comment: Is this question still not clear? Could you guys point out where you are confused? Why does someone lock my question and never check it or unlock it again?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try [Crop Upload](http://www.cropupload.com), a HTML5-based javascript plugin which crops the image in the canvas element, converts the canvas to a blob and uploads it as png or jpeg to the server by AJAX. It doesn't need any server-side code at all, but it can only run in those browsers which support HTML 5.

**EDIT: The link to the plugin has expired.**

Comment: This library provides with only one function call to both crop and upload images, which is great.

Comment: The Crop Upload URL's expired, can you update it please?

Comment: @Avoen Can you provide the new URL?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [Filepicker.io](https://www.filepicker.io/), which offers a JavaScript based filepicker that includes cropping/resizing functionality and supports uploading to S3 and other cloud storage services, without the need for server-side code. Note that some features require a paid plan.

Comment: Thanks. It seems good, but it is too heavy for me.

Comment: you might be able to find something flash-based that works somewhat like pixlr's online photo editor

Comment: Here's an article on pixlr's website on how to integrate their online photo editor with your website: https://support.pixlr.com/hc/en-us/articles/202846694-The-Pixlr-API-embedding-Pixlr-web-applications-in-your-own-site